# annotation for the documentation differs from the annotation for the type checking

Tags: python, python-typing

I need some help how to write the type hints, and it is not purely technical.

As an example, imagine a `get_state()` function returning the current state as a string.

The documentation states the `initialize()` must be called first and the result of `get_state()` is undefined prior to initialization. Actually it returns `None` when uninitialized, but that is an implementation detail.

The annotation could be:

1. `get_state() -> str` which is correct assuming a proper usage. I find it helpful from the developer's point of view, but `mypy` complains because it is clear that the return value could be also `None`.
2. `get_state() -> str|None` which matches the reality the most, but may change in the future and it introduces `mypy` warnings everywhere the return value is used and is obviously expected to be a string there.
3. `get_state() -> Any` which exactly matches the documented API, but is useless.

So, who is the main recipient of the information in the annotation? Is it the developer getting additional information when reading the code? Or is it the type checker tool like the `mypy` that tries to find possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `str|None` is what you want.

In my view, type annotations in Python try to reap some of the same benefits that static type systems bring to languages that have them. Good examples of languages with strong static type systems are Haskell and Rust. In such languages type annotations can never overpromise, like would happen with `get_state() -> str`. So that possibility is ruled out. `get_state() -> str|None` happens to be what the code is capable of supporting, so that is one option, and the documentation should probably then reflect that as well. If the developers think that this return type is likely to change or be different on different systems then it could be reasonable to go for a type like Any, but that would also have implications for how this function should be used. If all you know about this function is that it could return Any(thing) then what exactly can you do with this value? You could test whether it is a string and then use it as a string, but is that the way recommended in the documentation? If yes then the Any type is reasonable, if not then not.

Comment: Thanks for you comparison with other languages

Answer (score -1):

These annotations are mostly for the developer as they don't affect runtime. That said, the type checker is also there to make your life easier. So if any of these are making it harder for you don't have to use them...

And more practically, can you return an empty sting ('') instead of None?